# How can I join in data from a key : value meta table in mysql?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Say I have three tables in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`username` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `users_meta` (
`meta_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`user_id` INT NOT NULL ,
`key` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
`value` TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `posts` (
`post_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`user_id` INT NOT NULL ,
`content` TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

The table users_meta is just a key-value store of information about users, such that we can add any piece of information we want.

Say I added a key => value pair to the users_meta table for each user where the key was "age", and the value was a number representing their age.

Given this set of circumstances, what's the best way to select the first 10 posts ordered by user age?

Comment: The best way is to abandon that structure as quickly as humanly possible. It is the worst possible database design for querying.

Comment: In that case, how would you solve the issue of allowing any piece of metadata to be applied to a user?

Comment: I disagree with HLGEM.. I like that struct especially when the associated metadata will be sparsely applied to my primary table (users in this case)

Comment: TI think the actual use case for this type of structure is not well represented by my example.  This is more appropriate for "custom fields" applied to an object, rather than something like age, which would probably be more appropriately tied to the users table directly, as a few people have suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like putting the condition of the join in the join itself to be clear that I want a limited join:

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.content
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN users_meta um 
    ON (u.user_id = um.user_id) AND um.key = 'age'
INNER JOIN posts p 
    ON (p.user_id = u.user_id)
ORDER BY um.value
limit 10
```

Comment: In my opinion it mixes join and selection operators which makes code less readable.

Comment: I selected this answer because it makes joining multiple meta fields simpler, since you can join the meta table multiple times.  That's not really present in my example, but I think a good use case for this type of random metadata stucture.

Answer (score 1):

If you order by user age only, you will select 10 posts of the same user (the youngest one).

I would suggest to denormalize and store age in users table directly.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @KOHb, but if that's exactly what you want, here is the query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 p.id, p.content
FROM users u JOIN users_meta um ON (u.user_id = um.user_id) 
             JOIN posts p ON (p.user_id = u.user_id)
WHERE um.key = 'age'
ORDER BY um.value
```